# Write file in sub-directory in Android

Tags: java, android, file-io, filesystems

I'm trying to save a file in a subdirectory in Android 1.5.
I can successfully create a directory using

```
_context.GetFileStreamPath("foo").mkdir();
```

(_context is the Activity where I start the execution of saving the file) but then if I try to create a file in foo/ by

```
_context.GetFileStreamPath("foo/bar.txt");
```

I get a exception saying I can't have directory separator in a file name ("/").

I'm missing something of working with files in Android... I thought I could use the standard Java classes but they don't seem to work...
I searched the Android documentation but I couldn't fine example and google is not helping me too...

I'm asking the wrong question (to google)...

Can you help me out with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood what I was missing.
Java File classes works just fine, you just have to pass the absolute path where you can actually write files.

To get this "root" directory I used _context.getFilesDir(). This will give you the root of you application. With this I can create file with `new File(root + "myFileName")` or as Sean Owen said `new File(rootDirectory, "myFileName")`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use path directly, but you must make a file object about every directory.
I do not understand why, but this is the way it works.

NOTE: This code makes directories, yours may not need that...

```
File file = context.getFilesDir();
file.mkdir();

String[] array = filePath.split("/");
for (int t = 0; t < array.length - 1; t++) {
    file = new File(file, array[t]);
    file.mkdir();
}

File f = new File(file, array[array.length - 1]);

RandomAccessFileOutputStream rvalue = new RandomAccessFileOutputStream(f, append);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `getDir()` to get a handle on the "foo" directory as a `File` object, and create something like `new File(fooDir, "bar.txt")` from it.